# Editor not changing/accepting JS events

Tags: magento2, editor

So I am trying to make a slideshow appear on a page. The core code is based on a slideshow found on W3Schools. The whole lot works in Sublime text/Chrome, but as soon as I try to run it through magento, it fails, and I think I know why.
When I try to add code to the HTML editor it sometimes doesn't register it. I found that like 90% of the code is correctly copied, except for the 'onclick="currentSLide(1/10)"' event. And I think that is where my code fails.

So I established the problem, now for the solution. But I am at a loss.

I can't add it manually in the HTML editor, because everytime I do that, it just gets erased the second I click *"Save and Continue".* I tried to give the images the event through the normal editor with **"insert/edit attributes",** but saving that makes it dissapear too, even before *"save and continue".* Its like the editor just doesn't register these changes.

Anyone experienced this too or know the solution?

Thanks in advance!